# Any hosts support asp.net 4.0 yet - Ideally want green hosting

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, hosting, .net-4.0

I realise it's  vry soon after launching, but I'm keen to develop website in 4.0, but obviously need a host.
If there are none hosting 4.0 yet, any one aware of timescales.
UK hosts needed.

**edit:**

I would like to use GREEN HOSTING, so anyone aware of UK host supporting .net 4.0 using green energy!
Thanks

Comment: Did you end up picking a web host? Just interested in how it's working out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disadvantage of DiscountASP.NET is that they don't offer MySQL databases and you have to pay extra for Microsoft SQL DB.

After a lot of searching I have found [Arvixe web hosting](https://affiliates.arvixe.com/track.php?id=1080&url=59) which offers unlimited *x* (where x is whatever you want) and they have .NET 4.0.

I could not find information about their "greenness".

Comment: "Extra for Microsoft SQL DB" is an understatement. Expect to pay an extra $20-40 a month for your databases.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, mysql support would be preferential

Comment: How is Arvixe working out for you? Im thinking of signing up with them.

Comment: I experienced some initial problems with the control panel, but they fixed that. And last week they had to bring the server down for maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

[Discount ASP.Net](http://www.discountasp.net/) currently offer:

- .Net 4.0 hosting
- European (actually UK <sup>1</sup>) or US based
- support for ASP.Net MVC2
- .Net RIA services

I signed up for their free .Net 4.0 sandbox environment a few weeks ago, but haven't really played with it so cannot comment on their quality of service and support. They do seem to be widely used though, and the free offer was mentioned by Brad Abrams from Microsoft.

<sup>1</sup> [Data centre details](http://support.discountasp.net/KB/a2/general-information-on-discountaspnet-european-uk-data.aspx)

Comment: yeah, looks comprehensive and good value...In an ideal world I want to build applications ethically/eco-friendly. Any suggestion here or am I living in hope!

Comment: I think you're asking a bit much to get UK .Net 4.0 green hosting a few days after the release of .Net 4.0. You could get a dedicated server with a host that does green hosting (eg. RackSpace http://www.rackspace.co.uk/managed-hosting/hosting-solutions/managed-hosting/green-hosting/) and put what you want on it, or go with the host that offers your features and offset the environmental cost by doing something else (eg. plant some trees, don't take a flight, etc...).

Comment: I know . Asked in hope ...:) I reckon I'll off set the carbon as you suggest. thanks

Answer (score 2):

[DiscountASP.NET](http://discountasp.net/) does.

Answer (score 0):

have you had a chance to look at [asphostcentral.com](http://www.asphostcentral.com)? This host provides asp.net 4.0 hosting at a mush more affordable price than other host + great reasonable amount of features?

Truly, if you guys are looking for alternatives, asphostcentral is worth checking :-)